# Event Delegation (checking whether e.target exists—why?)

Tags: javascript, events

I came across this fragment of code:

```
if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "LI") { // do stuff }
```

in this context

```
document.getElementById("parent-list").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "LI") {
        console.log("List item ", e.target.id.replace("post-", ""), " was clicked!");
    } 
});
```

I understand the second check, i.e., whether the nodeName is "LI", but I don't understand the reason for the first check. Why check if e.target is truthy/exists. Wouldn't it be guaranteed to exist if the code reached that point? In order for the click listener to trigger, a click would have to occur, which means that e.target would have to exist. What am I missing? What's the point of this check?

Comment: Some programmers are paranoid.

Answer (score 0):

As the [target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) property of the Event interface is a reference to the object onto which the event was dispatched the first check is not necessarily required.